# concrete 5 external form response position

Tags: forms, concrete5

At the moment I can output my external form response with

```
<?php if (isset($response)) { ?>
<div class="response"><?php echo $response?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

This only shows up when it is inside the form view. However I would like to put this at the top of the page, is this possible? Can I access it though a global variable or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

## AJAX Method

If your external form uses AJAX to submit you could simply return the response value from your controller by `echo`ing it.

Since Concrete5 uses jQuery it's trivial to handle the form submission and then the response. For instance the code below would demonstrate the submission within your form submit event, then the handling of the response:

```
var formData = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {
    $('#response').html(response);
})
```

Once the controller responds the html content of a div or similar with id 'response' will be populated with the data sent back. This way you can place something like `<div id="response"></div>` wherever you want on the page and the data will be placed in between those tags.

## GET/POST Method

If you don't want to use AJAX then another way this could be achieved would be via GET or POST. You would still place your `<div id="response"></div>` wherever you want the response to appear on the page, except in the page/view you would change it to something like `<div id="response"><?php if(!empty($_POST['response'])) { echo $_POST['response'] } ?>`.

This way whenever the POST value is set it is added to the document, otherwise the response remains blank.

Initially when the user goes to the page with the form the POST variable is not set, so there is no response shown. Once they fill in the form and submit the data is handled, you generate your response, and then return to that page with the POST variable populated with your response. Since the variable is populated this time the response is injected into your markup.

Details on how to return values back from a form are well covered in [this thread](https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/block_requests/pass-data-from-form-to-controller-and-back-again./).